# Why is Linq2Sql creating a new connection for every sproc call and keeping it open?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

This wasn't happening before, so I'm assuming something I did is causing this, yet I can't see what it could be.

I have linq2sql set up against a sql server 2005 database. I'm only using stored procedures.

Most of my procedures are working fine, but this one particular update proc sometimes get's fired a few hundred times in a row (cloning the details of a header record).

This is causing timeouts, and running a script to see open connections shows my app connections all sleeping and taking up space.

Any thoughts, advice?

My datacontext is setup as a static variable in a service class:

```
private static WarehouseSystemDataContext dc
{
    get
    {
        // It is being passed a closed SqlConnection object
        WarehouseSystemDataContext _dc = 
            new WarehouseSystemDataContext(Constants.getWarehouseSystemConn());
        _dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        _dc.CommandTimeout = 600;

        return _dc;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it goes without saying that you always surround consumers of `dc` in a `using` block?   (`using (foo.dc) { ... }`)

Comment: I don't usually. My previous understanding was that linq2sql manages  opening and closing connections for you. For the sake of this problem, I added a using block, but still no luck.

Comment: linq2sql will sometimes manage the state properly, and sometimes it won't.  When you completely iterate through a result set, it will close it at the end.  I've found that when using `.Single` it does not.  That being said, the connections will still get disposed of when GC'd, but that can sometimes happen sufficiently later to cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new connection each time the datacontext is referenced

```
private static WarehouseSystemDataContext _dc
private static WarehouseSystemDataContext dc
{
    get
    {
        if(_dc == null)
        {
        // It is being passed a closed SqlConnection object
        _dc = new WarehouseSystemDataContext(Constants.getWarehouseSystemConn());
        _dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        _dc.CommandTimeout = 600;
        }
        return _dc;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that? Since it is static, aren't I using the same DataContext every time? Which supposedly manages it's own connections? Shouldn't it be closing them when complete?

Comment: @IronicMuffin, in your question the instance is not static, here it is

Comment: You're right, I see the mistake now. With your setup, and a using statement, I get an ObjectDisposedException now...

Comment: You either need to make a new DataContext each time and wrap it in a using statement, or have a static object and dispose it when you app closes.  Don't wrap a static object in a using.

Comment: Taking out the using, everything seems to be working as desired. Thanks!

Comment: @IronicMuffin, just be careful to *never* set `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to true if you're using a static data context.